# Libvlc buffer locking

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, libvlc

I'm implementing a 3d VR player and for the video decoding I'm using Libvlc.

To render the video I have a texture buffer and a memory buffer, when VLC decodes a frame the data is copied by the main loop to the texture.

I've tested two different mechanisms to lock the memory buffer when vlc is dumping a frame, first I tried a mutex as the examples show but the performance is awful, also I've tested a lock-free mechanism using atomic operations, the performance is not perfect but better.

The best results I get are just not locking at all the buffer, it works very smooth but some times the main loop and vlc loop gets desinchronized and then tearing and stuttering are noticeable.

So my question is, what is the best approach to lock the buffer? any way to don't loss performance?

Here are the important code parts:

-Video context struct

```
typedef struct _videoContext
{
    libvlc_instance_t* instance;
    libvlc_media_t* media;
    libvlc_media_player_t* player;
    unsigned char *pixeldata;
    unsigned char currentFrame;
    int width;
    int height;
    int duration;
    int time;
    int volume;
    bool finished;
    std::atomic<bool> lock;

} videoContext;
```

-Video event functions

```
static void *lock(void *data, void **p_pixels)
{
    videoContext* context = (videoContext*)data;

    bool expected = false;

    while (!context->lock.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true))
        Sleep(0);

    p_pixels[0] = context->pixeldata;

    return NULL;
}

static void unlock(void *data, void *id, void *const *p_pixels)
{
    videoContext* context = (videoContext*)data;
    context->time = libvlc_media_player_get_time(context->player);
    context->lock.store(false);
    context->currentFrame++;

}
```

-Main loop function

```
if (vctx->currentFrame != currentFrame && vctx->lock.compare_exchange_strong(exchangeExpected, true))
{

    currentFrame = vctx->currentFrame;
    Texture::setData(&videoTexture, vctx->pixeldata, vctx->width, vctx->height);
    vctx->lock.store(false);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid the best approach will be go away from libvlc at all. At least I've decided to do it. With every new release they break video output interface more and more...

Comment: @RSATom Yeah, that's what I thought, the performance is very poor. What other decoding framework do you recommend?

Comment: I plan to use GStreamer. At least it designed to be used in foreign applications...

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will check it.